# MongoDB throws NullPointerException in Class DBTCPConnector

Tags: java, xml, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to get a grip using MongoDB with the Spring Data MongoDB framework. I tried severeal approaches to connect to my local DB and insert + retrieve some collections and documents, using the official [Spring Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/) and some simple examples like this [Hello-World-Demo](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/).

Actually, for the beginning I'm going to use the MongoTemplate to keep it simple. But now I'run into the following problem.

When I use the Spring Configuration with annotations configure the setting needed to connect to my local DB, everything works fine.
Otherwise When I use XML for the configuration, I run into an java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription

Here are my configuration files and the example code for connecting to the DB:

**Use Case 1** - Spring Configuration with annotations:

```
//package, imports etc. here
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    public @Bean MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "Test1");
    }

    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

Using the configuration class like this ...

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfiguration.class);
MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
ctx.close();
for (String s : mongoOperation.getCollectionNames()) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

.. creates this output:

```
documents
leute
system.indexes
system.users
```

**Use Case 2** - XML configuration (SpringConfig2.xml):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="Test1" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Using the configuration file like this ...

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig2.xml");
MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
ctx.close();
for (String s : mongoOperation.getCollectionNames()) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

.. results in this ***error***

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription(DBTCPConnector.java:404)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getMaxBsonObjectSize(DBTCPConnector.java:653)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getMaxBsonObjectSize(Mongo.java:641)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:81)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.DB.getCollectionNames(DB.java:510)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$13.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:1501)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$13.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:1499)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:394)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getCollectionNames(MongoTemplate.java:1499)
    at test.main(Test.java:28)
```

When debugging **DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription**, it seems that in the second case the private class variable *cluster* is for some reason not instantiated, leading to the described error.

What I'd like to know is: am I doing anything wrong within my XML-configuration or when using this config / context? Why does using XML-configuration end in an error, while using annotation configuration just works fine?

Basically (in the end) I just "copy+paste"'d the code examples from the official references for Spring / Spring Data MongoDB.

I'd appreciate any help / suggestions :)

Comment: PS: I use the latest [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) on Win 7 x64 (version 2.6.1 when writing this post). And the latest Spring Data MongoDB framework from [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb) (actually  "1.5.0.RELEASE")

Comment: use case 2 -> does the context need to be closed immediately ? ctx.close();

Comment: For this test cases I just need to call _ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");_ and then don't need it anymore.

And I'm closing it here, because Eclipse complaines of a "Resource leak" when I don't (although I'm not sure if it's really neccessary).

Comment: I executed with the same config, works for me. Did yourefer to http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/ ?

Comment: @TusharMishra: That's the example I was refering to, beside the official spring documentation (chapter 4. -> 4.3.5)

Comment: May be its some problem with the version 1.5.0, can you try this in pom.xml -> spring.framework.version 3.1.2.RELEASE, mongodb java driver 2.11.0, Spring data mongodb 1.2.0.RELEASE, cglib 2.2.2, spring-data-mongodb-log4j 1.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: I'll try and report back...

Comment: Just tried to change "spring-data-mongodb" to an older Version. Using "1.2.0.RELEASE" now throws an IllegalStateException "this Mongo has been closed", also at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector (I'll update the question with the error message).
But it does not change the behaviour - using XML for configuration results in an error.

PS: Just tried the release Version 1.5.1.RELEASE, same issue.

Comment: @TusharMishra:
Thank you - your hint regarding "does the context need to be closed immediately ? ctx.close();" did help me to track down where the error originates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from Tushar Mishra in the comments I was able to track down the origin of the error and why it occurs in one case but not in the other.
I'll try to explain in short, maybe it'll save someone some research time (or remember me if I perhaps run into this or a similar error again).

When closing either the *AnnotationConfigApplicationContext*-object (UC1) or the *AnnotationConfigApplicationContext*-object (UC2) with **ctx.close()**, from somewhere 
org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean#destroy() is invoked. As far as I understood, within there used singleton beans get destroyed by invoking the destroy()-methods 
of each of those beans.

In short: closing the XXApplicationContext-object also destroys the MongoFactoryBean and with it closes the connection to the MongoDB.
So using c**tx.close()** at the described position leads to using a MongoOperations-object on a closed connection at the next line, resulting in the described NullPointerException.

And for why the sample code with Annotations (UC1) runs fine, whereas the sample code configured with XML (UC2) just breaks with an NullPointerException:
In UC1, the org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean#destroy()-call is interupted by some DisposableBeanMethodInterceptor, which tries to redirect to a dispose() method. 
But there is no method implemented in MongoFactoryBean, so the Mongo-connection stays alive and can be used even after ctx.close() was invoked. I think the connection will get killed later by the garbage collector, leading to the same error.

I'm not sure what to make of this, yet. If I should implement a dispose()-method myself or something alike. But at least I figured out, why this code sample behave different, although supposed to do the same thing.

Maybe it helps someone. Thanks again, Tushar, for giving a hint to the right direction.